# React js character limitation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, char

Im trying to implement a chartercter limit for a textArea in react js 
here is my code.

```
state = {
  chars_left: 140;
}

handleWordCount = event => {
  const charCount = event.target.value.length;
  const maxChar = this.state.chars_left;
  const charLength = maxChar - charCount;
  this.setState({ chars_left: charLength });
}

<textArea
  rows={6}
  type="text"
  maxLength="140"
  required
  onChange={this.handleWordCount}
/>
```

{`${this.state.chars_left}`}

I have a function that should that show how many character the user is typing and it starts at 140  but it skips tons numbers every time i type something like 130 when i type a single character

what could the problem be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is you are keep updating the chars_left attribute based on the old value

follow will work as expected

```
state = {
   chars_left: 140;
}

handleWordCount = event => {
    const charCount = event.target.value.length;
    const charLeft = 140 - charCount;
    this.setState({ chars_left: charLeft});
}
```

My example code can be improved by dynamically  getting the maxlengt attr

Comment: Sometimes the user deletes characters, and must be added to the length of the character. But this function still reduces the length of the character

I think the function should be such that it detects that the user is deleting characters or adding characters.

Answer (score 1):

That was happening because everytime your were trying to subtract the number of characters that are there in textare from characters left. Define a new variable or state called `max_char` and get `char_left` by subtracting length from `max_char`. Also you dont need to write `this.state.char_left` in backticks since you are already using `{}`

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
          chars_left: 140,
          max_char:140
        }

       handleWordCount = event => {
        const charCount = event.target.value.length;
        const maxChar = this.state.max_char;
        const charLength = maxChar - charCount;
        this.setState({ chars_left: charLength });
  }
   
   
   render() {

      return (
         <div>
          <textArea
            rows={6}
            type="text"
            maxLength="140"
            required
            onChange={this.handleWordCount}
          />
          <p>{this.state.chars_left}</p>
        </div>
     )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code helps you to be able to count the length of the character when entering text in the Textarea element.
One of the advantages of this function is that it detects the user deleting characters or adding them.

Here you can use this code snippet:

- Use the useState() hook to create the content state variable and set its value to that of value prop, trimmed down to limit characters.
- Create a method setFormattedContent, which trims the content down to limit characters and memoize it, using the useCallback() hook.
- Bind the onChange event of the  to call setFormattedContent with the value of the fired event.

  ```
  const LimitedTextarea = ({ rows, cols, value, limit }) => {
  const [content, setContent] = React.useState(value.slice(0, limit));

  const setFormattedContent = React.useCallback(
    text => {
      setContent(text.slice(0, limit));
    },
    [limit, setContent]
  );

  return (
    <>
      <textarea
        rows={rows}
        cols={cols}
        onChange={event => setFormattedContent(event.target.value)}
        value={content}
      />
      <p>
        {content.length}/{limit}
      </p>
    </>
  );
  ```

  };
  Examples
  ReactDOM.render(
  ,
  document.getElementById('root')
  );

Comment: I think instead of 
const [content, setContent] = React.useState(value.slice(0, limit));
you can have just 
const [content, setContent] = React.useState('');

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show certain amount of characters use the following code.

```
 {`${textToShow.substring(0, 70)}... `}
```

Here instead of "textToShow" you can use your own text that you want to slice.

Comment: `{`${num.desc.split(" ").splice(0, 25).join(" ")}...`}`

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are basically using one variable to keep track of both the max number of characters, but also for how many chars remain.

I would also change `maxLength` in your textArea to use the state variable, instead of hard-coding it.

Try using two variables for this, like in the example below:

```js
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {chars_left: 140, max_chars: 140};
  }
  
  handleWordCount = event => {
    const charCount = event.target.value.length;
    const maxChar = this.state.max_chars;
    const charLength = maxChar - charCount;
    this.setState({chars_left: charLength});
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <textArea
          rows={6}
          type="text"
          maxLength={this.state.max_chars}
          required
          onChange={this.handleWordCount}
        />
        <div>{this.state.chars_left}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById('myapp'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="myapp"></div>
```

---

Though, I would make another small change:

```
this.state = {chars_left: null, max_chars: 140};
...
<div>{this.state.chars_left || this.state.max_chars}</div>
```

This way `chars_left` doesn't need to know what `max_chars` is set to, and you have 1 less variable to manage should the limit change in the future.