# How can I limit the number of characters per line in a textArea using React?

Tags: html, reactjs, textarea

I want to limit the number of characters in a textarea **per line**. I am using React.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
<textarea data-row-maxlength={80} data-limit-row-len="true" rows={20}> </textarea>
```

The problem is `data-row-maxlength` is ignored.

I have also tried to find a smart textarea component on npm but couldn't find one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React js character limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43777555/react-js-character-limitation)

Comment: Yeah sorry the question was misleading. I want to limit the number of characters per line and not overall.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<textarea maxlength=10 data-limit-row-len="true" rows=20> </textarea>
```

Comment: This sets the general character limit. But I unlimited characters in general and a character limit per line.

Comment: you would have to use js